# Monodevelop External Console

Tags: xterm, monodevelop

Ubuntu 12.04. When I run MonoDevelop (IDE) using native shell, Unity, the MonoDevelop External Console that appears during debugging is gnome-terminal.

But if I use another window manager (for instance i3wm), MonoDevelop External Console is xterm.

Any workaround to make the IDE 'think' it is in GNOME environment and make it use gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 4):

Way late, but same issue for me using awesomeWM. I just made a symlink called `xterm` in `/usr/bin` pointing to `/usr/bin/<TERMINALOFCHOICE>` (`urxvt` in my case).

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/urxvt /usr/bin/xterm
```

Working fine so far.

Answer (score 3):

From the source code of monodevelop, we can find that if the environment variable `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` exists, `gnome-terminal` will be used. With this knowledge, you can run monodevelop using:

```
export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=1 && monodevelop
```

Comment: `export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID= && monodevelop` did the trick for me. Instead of using `unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` everytime.