# MonoDevelop external console error

Tags: gnome-terminal, monodevelop

When I try to run a project with MonoDevelop (version 7.8.4) with an external console.
I got the following error:

[image: MonoDevelop error]

I've looked around and found that, in fact, `gnome-terminal` is not stored where it's looking, but elsewhere:

```
$ whereis gnome-terminal
gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper /usr/bin/gnome-terminal /usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.1.gz
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue and knows of a way around it? I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've tried nothing and we're all out of ideas! I eventually tried following the advice from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/223765/1423770). I looked up the location of `gnome-terminal-server` like so:

```
$ whereis gnome-terminal-server
gnome-terminal-server: /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
```

Then I made the directory where MonoDevelop was looking for the terminal server.

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/lib/gnome-terminal-server
```

Then I made a symbolic link, redirecting MonoDevelop from that directory to the actual binary.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

And that did the trick!